# How do you declare independent consulting income for schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, freelance

other than my full time job, I do independent consulting for an online educational site, for which I get a variable amount paid every month which varies between a fraction of my regularly salary, to sometimes a little more than my salary.

I do not have any sort of contract with the company for whom I do consulting. Do I show this as freelance income? How does this work without any "official" documents?

P.S. Let me know if you need any further information to help answer this question.

Comment: Do you get this amount in your bank account? or Cash?

Comment: @HankyPanky It comes into my bank account via. Payoneer.com. The PAN Card (tax document) is also connected to the Payoneer account, so the amount is reflected for Tax as well.

Comment: @HankyPanky I haven't filed an ITR (Paying tax for the amount to the govt.) for it yet, since it started around 8 months ago. ITR filing happens after July.

Comment: That doesn't sound problematic then. I would state to them what you just stated here. That you do free lancing work on your free time and all those incoming bank transactions are for your supplementary income.

Comment: OK. so just explaining the incoming credits in the cover letter to them should be ok? even though the amount might be same or more than the full time salary?

Comment: In my (useless - it can't impact the decision) opinion, yes it should be ok. There is nothing wrong with variable income from your side business as long as it is done the right way. If you had said all of this income was in the form of cash and not via a bank account that would be hard to justify.

Comment: All right. Understood. Thank you for the clarification @HankyPanky

Comment: Providing invoices to support the explanation would be ideal. There’ve apparently been some legal issues with Payoneer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payoneer

Comment: @Traveller Oh! I didn't notice they had legal issues. But, do you think it will be a problem in my case? Since, for me, the company pays via. payoneer, and the credited amount gets auto transferred to my local bank account. Nothing stays in the Payoneer account.

Comment: IMHO the fact a company pays you through an online money transfer service rather than direct to your account makes no difference from the point of view of proving income / provenance of funds. Presumably you invoice the client for whom you do the consulting work in order for them to pay you via Payoneer, so I’d provide those along with your full-time job evidence